# Is there a central repository for soundscape literature?

Tags: soundscape, literature

Soundscape measurements can provide critical context to bioacoustics studies, and there’s been a lot of recent developments in soundscape technology and research. A central repository for soundscape literature would be very helpful for our bioacoustics community.

Answer (score 12):

There is a public Soundscape repository on Zotero! https://www.zotero.org/groups/58164/soundscape
To join and contribute references, please create a Zotero account and request to be a member.

The current collection is by no means complete and by making it public the intent is to build a collaborative resource for the broader community of researchers, students, and practitioners. The more contributors the more we can learn from the diversity of approaches and applications out there!

The term "soundscape" is used differently depending on the community and this repository is inclusive of these different uses and covers a wide-range of topics, including wildlife and human applications and comparisons across seascapes and landscapes. There is no strict criteria for adding references, but methodologies that are integrative, meaning the biological, human and physical dimensions are considered, are encouraged.

Comment: Yes, it's an important point: **The term "soundscape" is used differently depending on the community**. Some refer only to human perception, some to any outdoor sound recording...